# ListBox, get selected item issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, listbox

I'm new to C# asp.net and I'm having trouble getting the selected item. Here is the code behind:

```
List<string> figuritasSelecionadas = new List<string>();
    this.lblMensaje.Visible = false;
    decimal total = 0;

    foreach (ListItem lf in this.ListaFiguritas.Items)
    {
        if (lf.Selected)
        {
            figuritasSelecionadas.Add(lf.Text);
            total += Decimal.Parse(lf.Value);
        }
    }
```

The problem here is that it doesn't matter which item is selected, because when it reaches the if the first item is marked as true. And I have no idea why it's doing this.

Here is how I load the ListBox:

```
private void cargarFiguritas()
{
    List<Figurita> figuritas = Sistema.Instancia.figuritasQueFaltan(usuarioActivo);
    this.ListaFiguritas.DataSource = figuritas;
    this.ListaFiguritas.DataValueField = "Precio";
    this.ListaFiguritas.DataTextField = "NumeroFigurita";
    this.ListaFiguritas.DataBind();
    Session["ListaFiguritas"] = figuritas;
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    usuarioActivo = (string)Session["nombreUsuario"];
    this.lblUsuario.Text = (string)Session["nombreUsuario"] + " tiene un total de: " + Session["Monedas"].ToString() + " monedas";
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        cargarFiguritas();
    }

}
```

Here is the aspx code:

```
    <asp:ListBox ID="ListaFiguritas" runat="server" Height="180px" Width="110px" SelectionMode="Single">
    </asp:ListBox>
```

Comment: What does the data in figuritas look like? Can you post your ASPX page?

Comment: there doesn't seem to be any issue with the code unless you are explicitly setting the first value to be selected somewhere else in your code, as @lucidgold mentioned show some aspx code

Comment: There i added the aspx

Comment: I am not sure but I tried it and this code works perfectly for me..

Comment: Can it be that the  listbox declared on the aspx page should in side an updatePanel ?

Comment: In the sample that I created the listbox is not inside an update panel, in fact i didnt use an update panel on my page

Comment: I'm clue less of what could be happening

Comment: Found the problem the problem was in the value, they all had the same value, that was why it was selecting the first one.